# Ubuntu 18. Sound disappeared

Tags: ubuntu

I have a problem with sound on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, with KDE.
Sound disappeared completely.

My sound devices in tray disappeared and "Dummy output" has appeared instead.

I tried everything I was able to find and nothing work out.

aplay -L output:     https://pastebin.com/QVXKGhBw

Please help

Comment: try reinstall pulseaudio `sudo apt-get install --reinstall pulseaudio`

Comment: Didn't work out